How can I use the result of CHECKSUM TABLE?
SELECT * FROM (CHECKSUM TABLE mytable);

This isn't valid SQL. So how can I access the values returned by this command ?
Looking at this answer it says you can't save the results, but surely there is some way of accessing them and using them ? The result is displayed on my screen, therefore the result exists and is transmitted from the engine to the outside.

You know that this in invalid SQL. So the only result should be an error code.

@Wiimm Obviously I want to access the values returned by CHECKSUM TABLE...

Within mysql, no, you do not have any option to access the returned data. Checksum is a utility statement, not a proper sql statement that returns a resultset. Use it from an external script and process the results there.

@Shadow CHECKSUM isn't a utility statement, per docs : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/sql-utility-statements.html

It is under the database admin section. Same difference.

@JohnJohn CHECKSUM is built-in procedure. It acts as any other procedure (both built-in and user-defined), its output is sent immediately to the output stream and cannot be captured within MySQL, so its output cannot be used as a datasource.

To be honest, the answer you linked is still valid and tells you what you can do to capture  checksum table's output, so I'm marking this question duplicate of the linked one.

This is the kind of stupid implementation decisions that I keep moving things over to postgres for...

@JohnJohn I do not agree with you on this. These are not proper sql statements, but administrative ones. There is no real need to handle them as something that returns an sql resultset. Mysql's sql implementation is not complex enough anyway to write complete database management solutions in sql only.

Does PostgreSQL support any statement other than SELECT or VALUES in a subquery?
